# Node.js firebase integration

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I hope you can help me I am making an API with Node.js (stateless) connected to firebase the main objective is to create users and work with collections (Add, edit, consult) information I am using the following firebase module

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

When I try to insert data, as such there is no user logged in, and the methods to insert information or delete or modify, I get back user permission errors.

code example:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
let botRef = db.collection('bot').doc(bot.botId);
botRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        botRef.update({ color: bot.color, botname: bot.botname, welcomemessage: bot.welcomemessage });
```

What should I do? or should i use the admin module of firebase? since as such in this API there is no login to firebase (since it is a stateless API) thanks for your help

Comment: I've posted a solution, please check it out. The issue may be due to admin-sdk because its missing. Let me know if you need more assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Firebase Admin SDK for this.  It just wraps the Google Cloud Firestore SDK for node, so it has the same API as that.

You will need to initialize the SDK with a service account.  Then, your code will have full read and write access to everything in the database, bypassing any security rules you have set up for actual users.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the modules like this:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

By the way, don't forget to install `firebase-admin` before deploying your program. Run this command to install it:

`$ npm install firebase-admin --save` in your terminal.

This will grant admin permissions to your cloud functions which means no restrictions on reading or writing the data.

Even if you have any firebase realtime database or cloud firestore rules, it will override them.